# estou começando com react native e sempre me da esse erro cant find variable:component

Tags: syntax-error

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
index.js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native'
import App from './app'
import {name as appName} from './app.json'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName,() => App)

app.js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends component {
  render(){
    return(
      <text>test</text>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

A palavra "component" deveria estar com a primeira letra em maiúsculo. Além disso, o "text" deve ser importado da biblioteca "react-native". Os nomes dos componentes em React sempre devem começar com letra maiúscula.  Altere o seu código para ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
import {AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native'
import App from './app'
import {name as appName} from './app.json'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName,() => App)

app.js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Text>test</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: AJUDOU MUITO vlw , vou prestar mais atençao nesses detalhes

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa importar o Component para usá-lo, e ela deve estar com a primeira letra em maiúscula:

`import React, { Component } from 'react';`